# I need to access a url_helper method in an observer, how can I do it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, observers

I've got an observer that is being used to generate some activity logs.

Those activity logs need to have links to the actual site activities so that when they're displayed it's easy to jump to the corresponding page. However observers can't access url_helpers (at least by default).

If I don't store the simple link then I'm going to have to store the details of the page that the link should be to and then deserialize later which seems pretty silly.

How can I generate a link within the observer?

Answer (score 1):

Just try it with Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.yourhelper_path

Comment: Although, if you are including this in your observer you may get this error if you do not set the default host "ArgumentError: Missing host to link to!" -- In this case you need to set the default host: Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host] = 'localhost:3000'